# How to get android calendar event when I have event ID

Tags: android, calendar

Is it possible to get calendar event when I have specific ID or it is necessary to read all events and compare to my ID?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think is better to find it based on information of the event(title,description),because when you want to edit a speceific event meanwhile the user can delete himself your event,and create another event which might have the same ID as yours.So you will get the wrong event to edit.

So i think is safer to find your's choice event based to title or description ...

For example if you want to delete an event(android 2.2 example):

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), "title=? and description=?", new String[]{"The title of the event", "Description of the event"});
```